# ROS (TheConstructSim) : cannot declare 2D vector

Tags: c++, ros

I am working with TheConstructSim and I try to declare a 2D vector `std::vector<std::vector<int> >` but I am unable to do it since each time the compiler converts it to `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` which is obviously not valid.

Is there a way to avoid this problem?

Comment: You need to update to a modern C++ compiler. This is perfectly valid in modern C++.

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: Do what? Update to a modern C++ compiler? This depends entirely on what operating system and platform you are using. This is something that has no universal set of instructions that only need to be followed, in an identical manner, on every operating system in the world, from MS-Windows, to Macs, to mainframes, to embedded systems.

Comment: "The Construct" is an online platform you know : https://www.theconstructsim.com/

Comment: No, I didn't know that. So, you're saying that there's some kind of a C++ compiler there, that compiles and executes code that you provide? If so, then the direction for updating their C++ compiler is probably something that the administrators of that web site will need to address, instead of people who are using their web site.